# Is this a valid edit ?

Tags: discussion, edits, review

I'm troubled about following edit:

Is it valid or invalid?
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2524680

It seems like the editor really went out of his or her way to clean up this post; however, the author might not even recognize it as his or her post anymore.

Should i approve or reject with "too radical" ?

Comment: seems like it got approved already, i'm still not sure tough

Comment: I don't know enough about JavaScript, but is there a way of indenting the code without splitting it into a separate function? I mean, the `<copy_above_js_function_here>` part is pretty sloppy, not to mention the incorrect addition of "I am a beginner in `javascript`". Otherwise it is a pretty solid edit.

Comment: @doubleDown The problem is that it's not actually straight javascript code. It's javascript code embedded in what I'm guessing is an objective-c string. That probably limits what can be done as far as formatting within the string itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit substantially improves the question, and does not change what is being asked.

- The code changes made an entirely unreadable block of code *much* more readable, and did not change the contents of the code.
- The non-code changes helped make the question clearer, and corrected a lot of the grammatical problems - again, without changing the actual question being asked.

I would agree with the approvers that this is a good edit.

There *are* more corrections that could be made - such as removing incorrect backticks, but what was done was a substantial improvement. If anything, I'd suggest using the `Improve` button to correct the few remaining issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can click on **Improve** button in your review session and add your clean up. You can also set check whether the suggested edit was useful or not.. I must agree the post did add too much irrelevent details like `I am a beginner in javascript` as well